# Installation failing to install samples

Tags: phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I am running Win 11 and here are the versions of the relevant components, I believe

X:\Macif\MikeBrice\PHPapps\Macif>composer -V
Composer version 2.5.4 2023-02-15 13:10:06

X:\Macif\MikeBrice\PHPapps\Macif>php -v
PHP 8.3.0 (cli) (built: Nov 21 2023 17:48:00) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

X:\Macif\MikeBrice\PHPapps\Macif>git -v
git version 2.43.0.windows.1

I started with the command composer init and searched for the package phpoffice/phpspreadhseet. After attempting to answer the questions, not all of which I understood, the process completed without any error messages.

The directory vendor was created and in this space a sub-directory of phpoffice was created with phpspreasheet, so I assume the basic install was completed.

I entered the following command in an attempt to have the samples installed/downloaded:

composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --prefer-source

This completed without errors:

X:\Macif\MikeBrice\PHPapps\Macif>composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --prefer-source
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
1 package you are using is looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
No security vulnerability advisories found
Using version ^1.29 for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

X:\Macif\MikeBrice\PHPapps\Macif>

However there is still no subdirectory named samples in the phpspreadsheet directory.

What am I missing

Installation  of phpspreadsheet with sample scripts

Answer (score 0):

You're missing this part in the phpspreadsheet project :

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/.gitattributes

As per [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_export_ignore), having it ignored from exports means it won't be included in the directory if used as a third-party vendor.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have no idea what it is I am supposed to do. The phpSpreadSheet documentation at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ simply states that I should enter the command composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --prefer-source, which I did, giving me a result I did not expect. If I am missing something to do with gitattributes, whatever they are, why did the phpSpreadSheet install process not include this stuff ? Sorry but I need a little more detail.

Comment: I think it is very not clear on their end, but what they expect you to do is basically to clone the repository somewhere along your project, and use that clone as part of your project.

Because as stated here https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md , the option --prefer-source is normally used to mention that you don't want to check the distant repository in priority, but another one that you have to specify in your project.

Therefore, you can either download the samples directly from the project via Github, or clone the project and use it as a preferred source. Let me know if you need more